# change subject of formspree with ajax

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ajax

I'm using formspree within an angular app. Everything is working except I can't seem to change the subject of the email.

Html...

```
<form id="bookingForm" action="https://formspree.io/your@email.com"
  method="POST">
  <input type="text" name="{{client.name}}">
  <input type="{{client.email}}" name="_replyto">
  <input type="hidden" name="_subject" value="Request from {{client.name}}">
  <!-- some other info -->
  <input type="submit" value="Send">
</form>
```

JS...

```
$bookingForm = $('#bookingForm');
 $bookingForm.submit(function(e) {
 e.preventDefault();
 $.ajax({
   url: '//formspree.io/your@email.com',
   method: 'POST',
   data: {
    client: $scope.client.name,
    email: $scope.client.email,
    phone: $scope.client.phone,
    // some other info 
  },
  dataType: 'json',
 });
});
```

The _replyto seems to be working but _subject is not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add '**_subject**' to your post request and remove the name attribute from the subject input field:

```
$bookingForm = $('#bookingForm');
    $bookingForm.submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        url: '//formspree.io/your@email.com',
        method: 'POST',
        data: {
            client: $scope.client.name,
            email: $scope.client.email,
            phone: $scope.client.phone,
            _subject: "Text here"
    },
    dataType: 'json',
 });
});
```