# _subject hidden input not working formsubmit.co in React form

Tags: form-submit, subject

I am trying to use FormSubmit to submit a basic form from my React app to my gmail account. When I use the _subject hidden input from their documentation it works in their live demo but not in my code. Any suggestions??? And yes, I am using styled components so the form is not all HTML, but the form works as is, but the subject line always the same right now...

I have tried hard coding a subject instead of using my state variable, taking out my subject input and only having hidden _subject with hard coded value, I have tried using  and  fields, and I have tried making the input a styled component like the rest of my inputs

Answer (score 0):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/42161567/20616453

I found this thread and it solved my question if anyone else has the same problem...putting the _subject in the response body fixes it!!!